# tshark: not able to apply filter while saving the captured packet

Tags: networking, cygwin, wireshark, packet-capture, tshark

We had a command which used to work with previous version of wireshark (1) but does not working with latest version (1.6.1)

"C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe"  -i \Device\NPF_{282F8D86-F9CC-4575-8F20-7E9F5B04BB89}  -l  -q -R "h245" -S  -T pdml  -w C:\capture_0.cap "(host 172.24.161.49 or host 172.24.161.34 and not port 80 and not port 23) and tcp"  1>C:\capture_0.xml

It is giving the error message: "tshark: Read filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured packets."

what is wrong with this command?

FYI - I do have a complete cygwin installed on this machine. Will it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with version 1.2.5 or earlier - it used to work back then. For some unknown reason this limitation was introduced.